# Why are the newer versions of pyqt5 not pre-compiled for windows?

Tags: pyqt5

Why (or where) are the newer versions of pyqt5 not pre-compiled for Windows?
Looking for 64-bit.

eg. https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt5/ only has zip/tar.gz

Do I need to compile myself?

Comment: Why don't you just look on the [pyqt website](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5)?

Comment: No idea what wheels is. Where is the straightforward "download now for w64" link??

Comment: Are you really not able to read the simple instructions: "So long as you are using a supported version of Python you can install PyQt5 from PyPi by running:  pip3 install PyQt5"?

Comment: What's pip? You're assuming a lot. Rather than being condescending, maybe answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and install the latest version of PyQt5 (5.15.0) using the pip (pip is the package installer for Python. You can use pip to install packages from the Python Package Index and other indexes).

First of all install the pip for Python 3 with the help of this instruction [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-windows).

Then simply use the following command:

```
python3 -m pip install pyqt5
```

If you encounter the following error:

```
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Follow the instruction in [this link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-python-3-windows).